# driver.hidekeyboard() throwing error in appium

Tags: java, android, selenium, automation, appium

I have used following code:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("FirstName")).sendKeys("Manoj");
driver.findElement(By.id("LastName")).sendKeys("Kumar");
driver.hideKeyboard();
```

As per this code,it entered first-name and last name.There after it should close the the android soft keyboard.However it is throwing following error.

```
FAILED: testCal
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 03:03:16'
System info: host: 'XXXXXX', ip: '10.XXX.XXX.XX', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_51'
Driver info: driver.version: AppiumDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:589)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
```

Comment: Is the app crashing after entering Last name?

Comment: No.App staying on same page.However soft-keyboard still visible.Its not hiding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to hide the keyboard after typing, its an workaround, but it will hide the keyboard.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("FirstName")).sendKeys("Manoj");
driver.findElement(By.id("LastName")).sendKeys("Kumar");
driver.back();
```

Comment: When I use driver.back(), page navigating into previous page.Its not closing soft keyboard.

Comment: Can u try clicking on empty area so that key board is hidden ?

Comment: Yes understood.But how to get the attribute for empty area.(i.e xpath or id or name of the empty path)

Comment: You can try xpath of empty area , or if u have id of sign in button you can try clicking on it if its visible

Comment: See my steps above.First step I am entering "Firstname".Once I reach this page my cursor moved into text box and soft-keyboard came to visible.Nw I need to close this keyboard.How can I?